# Return closest values to a specific column in R

Tags: r, dplyr

My dataset contains 500 observations. Here is any example of the data structure:

```
df <- data.frame(rating_mean=c(3.6, 4.0, 3.7, 4.8, 3.9, 5.1, 4.1, 4.3 ),
             actual_truth=c("true", "false", "false", "true", "true", "false", "false", "true"))
```

I would like to return the 60 items with a rating_mean closest to the value of 3.5 for "true" stimuli, and the same for "false" stimuli (so a total of 120 items). So far I have this but it's **not correct**:

```
df50 <- df %>%   group_by(actual_truth) %>%   top_n(n = 60, wt = rating_mean - 3.5)
```

Thank you.

Comment: `top_n(n=50, wt=abs(rating_mean-3.5))`. But if you want 60 items, why `n=50`? If this doesn't work, you'll need to be less vague by *"it's not correct"* (by including your expected output given this sample input).

Comment: The expected output is a list of the 60 "true" stimuli with a rating_mean closest to 3.5. And the same for "false" stimluli.

Comment: Emma, perhaps you missed my point about *"given this sample input"*. Please **literally** provide the expected output as a `data.frame` given these 8 rows and (say) `n=2` or something. It might be informative to read about fully-reproducible, MWE questions; I suggest at least one of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269, https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: While this may be moot given my suggestion (in my first comment) and/or @akrun's answer, in which case please keep this in mind with your next question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to `arrange` by 'actual_truth' and the `abs`olute difference between the 'rating_mean' and threshold value, then grouped by 'actual_truth', `slice` the first 60 observations

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   arrange(actual_truth, abs(rating_mean - 3.5)) %>% 
   group_by(actual_truth) %>%
   slice(seq_len(60))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much!